# I am thankful to Almighty Allah=God he/who bestowed us with this favour

Tags: pronouns

I am a bit confused about "He and Who" over here.
One of my friends told me that "Who" can't be used with name of "Allah".
I was really confused. 
I gave her several examples:
Such as;  (Start with the name of Allah=God who is the most kind of merciful.)
Actually,  I don't know how to use "Who" with the name of "Allah".

I am thankful to Almighty Allah Who bestowed us this favour. 
I am thankful to Almighty Allah He bestowed us this favour.

Comment: I feel this needs more context, you definitely can. You definitely, definitely can from an English language and grammatical point of view. *Just possibly* there's some religious dimension to this that I'm missing, but I don't know of any and I would wager that there would be few who follow any kind of symbolic, religious injunction against using 'who' with 'Allah' in English. Perhaps she was thinking of "Who" with a capital 'W' (as opposed to "who") in the middle of a sentence? (You *could* by the way write "Allah Who" but this is probably not very common)

Comment: I'm confused about "He and Who" over here.

Comment: No, it's a typo.  I edited "Who" right now.

Comment: Then I'm afraid I don't understand your question. "I am thankful to Almighty Allah who bestowed us this favour" is fine. "I am thankful to Almighty Allah **;** He bestowed us this favour" is fine, although less common I think and to me less natural and fluent. (P.S. We generally don't, in modern times, put a space before a piece of punctuation like a ; (so it should be Allah;) but otherwise I can't make it bold)

Comment: "And you see the mountains, thinking them rigid, while they will pass as the passing of clouds. [It is] the work of Allah, who perfected all things. Indeed, He is Acquainted with that which you do." Verse 27.88 of the Sahih International translation of the Quran. quran.com/27/88

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't a question about English; it's a question about religion and what is the appropriate pronoun to refer to God/Allah/Jehovah/Cheon-ju et. al.

Comment: This is not a question about religion, and I am confused about "He" and "Who".you people are saying that this question is related to religion, no.  That's wrong.  I am at sea about pronouns. You people are taking me wrong, please try to read my question very carefully. I am asking a grammatical term.

Comment: Do you have an example that doesn't involve a deity? Pronouns referring to God are more a question of theology and culture than language.

Comment: Yes, what about this.  God who created the sun, and the moon.